# How to create a separate project for entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

**Question**: I want to separate the JPA entities from the actual Java code.

**Reason**: I am developing a Java application using the spring and hibernate frameworks. I am using more than 400 entities, which increases the running time of Tomcat server during application development.

**What I have done**: To resolve this problem I have created the .class files of our entity classes, created the jar files of these, and imported the jar files into the application, which is not working in the application.

**Is it possible to deploy the entities to some other server and use into another server where all other code is running? If yes then how?**

**Please refer to any Java project architecture which resolves the above issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define them in a separate Maven project, and refer to that project as a dependency in your app? That way you only compile the entities when a change is made to that project.